# How should I distribute the Strength increments on a weapon I'm designing?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew

I designed a new weapon for one of my players (a warrior). The weapon provides several effects that level up with the character, but the main one is to take his Strength to 30 at level 20. There is an item in the manual that already does this, so I think it won't be excessive at level 20. My question is: is it better to equally distribute the Strength increments across all levels (he is at level 5 now), or to concentrate them at the last levels (for example, 16-20)?
Thank you.

Comment: VTC as opinion-based, this type of question might be better suited to a forum rather than the format of our site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Spreading out bonuses over time is better**

Strength is a key ability for most warriors so they are likely to want to increase it as they level up. If the sword you're making sets strength to a high value later on this could make their earlier resources put into strength feel meaningless. Obviously being strong without magic has its own advantages but if the character usually has access to this sword it won't come up often.

**The DMG provides guidance for pacing based on magic item rarity**

One way of determining pacing for items like this is to look when comparable magical effects become available. The belts of giant strength (DMG p. 155) seem to have exactly the effect you're giving the sword and scale from a, "Rare", version granting 21 strength to a, "Legendary", version granting 29 strength.

Next, the DMG p. 135 provides a table equating magic item rarity with character level. These levels aren't meant to be a hard and fast rules however they provide guidelines for when different tiers of magical items may become suitable. Unfortunately the higher power belts overlap in their rarity but since the level ranges are large you can work around it.

Putting it together and using some personal discretion to spread out matching rarities gives a pacing like:

```
Level 5, Str 21
Level 11, Str 23
Level 14, Str 25
Level 17, Str 27
Level 20, Str 29
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have another question: since it is a weapon and not a belt, should the increment apply only when he is using it or is the attunement sufficient?

Comment: @firion If you have another question, please post it as a fresh question. We have limited ability to serve questions posted in the comments section.